# Python putting labels on a geoplot.choropleth.map graph with projection gcrs.AlbersEqualArea()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, geopandas, choropleth

I am tying to plot a choropleth map with each region has their name on the polygons. When I remove the projection line, it works well but the map is stretched horizontally. When I use the  projection=gcrs.AlbersEqualArea() I get rid of the stretch but this time all the  labels are overlapping on the center. Has anyone any idea what might cause this problem? How can I get the labels appear on the polygons with the un-stretched projection?

```
ax = gplt.choropleth(df=map_data,
                projection=gcrs.AlbersEqualArea(),
               hue='population',
               figsize=(16,8),
               legend=True,
                cmap='BuGn',
                scheme=scheme_2,
                legend_kwargs={'loc': 'lower right'},
                edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.5,

)
map_data.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(s=x.population_abb, xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0],fontsize='x-small',fontstretch='ultra-expanded',  ha='center',bbox={'facecolor': 'white', 'alpha':0.3, 'pad': 2, 'edgecolor':'none'}),axis=1,);
```

The map:

[image]

Comment: I suspect that the coordinates `x.geometry.centroid.coords[0]` are in `long/lat` degrees. If I am right, you need to transform them to the projection coordinates (AlbersEqualArea) to get them right.

Answer (score 0):

The `x.geometry.centroid.coords[0]` coordinates are probably long/lat.
If you project them (using `gplt.crs.ccrs.AlbersEqualArea.transform_point`) they should appear at the expected location.

Here is a snippet that should work (and that I only got to work when using a subplot):

```
import geoplot as gplt
import geoplot.crs as gcrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


projection = gcrs.AlbersEqualArea()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8), dpi=100, subplot_kw={'projection': projection})
ax = gplt.choropleth(
    df=map_data,
    projection=projection,
    hue='population',
    legend=True,
    cmap='BuGn',
    scheme=scheme_2,
    legend_kwargs={'loc': 'lower right'},
    edgecolor='black',
    linewidth=0.5,
)


for x in map_data:
    # Project the coordinates in an AlbersEqualArea.
    xtran = gplt.crs.ccrs.AlbersEqualArea()
    xy = xtran.transform_point(x.geometry.centroid.coords[0][0], x.geometry.centroid.coords[0][1], gplt.crs.ccrs.PlateCarree())

    ax.annotate(
        s=x.population_abb,
        xy=xy,  # Use the transformed coordinates.
        fontsize='x-small',
        fontstretch='ultra-expanded',
        ha='center',
        bbox={'facecolor': 'white', 'alpha':0.3, 'pad': 2, 'edgecolor':'none'}),
        axis=1,
    )
```

I hope that helps :)